# iOS 12: How to force Wi-Fi connecting to use active scanning for access points or boost detection range?

Tags: ios, network, wifi

Most phones use passive scanning by default, where routers and access points advertise their names and they show up in the Wi-Fi connection menu. Think of this as a bunch of vendors at a venue wearing name tags, and the phone is a prospective customer picking a vendor by name tag.

Now suppose for some reason the router/access point you want to connect to isn't visible for some reason. Think of this as the above-mentioned vendor forgetting to wear a name tag or being visually blocked. In that case, you want to use active scanning, where the device connecting (the phone) sends a signal out to all access points in range asking if any of them match a given name. Think of this as a customer yelling out the name of a vendor to get their location.

The iOS 12 implementation appears to be missing this critical functionality. It repeatedly and falsely claims an access point in range with maximum signal strength (as tested on a MacBook Pro) isn't available. I manually entered the name of the access point and it also falsely claims "unable to connect".

How do I fix this and enable active scanning on iOS? In short, if an access point is in range, available for use, and I know its name as would be listed on the Wi-Fi connection menu, I should be able to manually enter its name and have it connect 100% of the time with no errors, just like I can do the same on my laptop.

Something else that may help diagnose the problem: A lot of Wi-Fi access points in range (as determined by the laptop) are absent from the list on the iPhone. In particular, another thing that could help is any way to increase the Wi-Fi detection range to the maximum possible value (comparable range to a laptop), even at the cost of extra battery drain. I did some searches for this and all the search results were dodgy sites that looked like scams.

Comment: FYI: before anyone asks the obvious, rebooting and clearing Wi-Fi network configurations to factory default didn't fix it

Comment: Does iOS support active scanning for wifi?  Were you able to do this before iOS 12?

Comment: The Wi-Fi's been defective even in iOS 11. I upgraded to iOS 12 specifically for quality fixes, which never happened.

Comment: Which fixes were promised that never happened?  I'm just struggling to determine if this is an actual **issue** or something that you **want** but Apple hasn't included.